# Linux - Restoring a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've written a vary basic shell script that moves a specified file into the dustbin directory.  The script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
#move items to dustbin directory
mv "$@" ~/dustbin/
echo "File moved to dustbin"
```

This works fine for me, any file I specify gets moved to the dustbin directory.  However, what I would like to do is create a new script that will move the file in the dustbin directory back to its original directory.  I know I could easily write a script that would move it back to a location specified by the user, but I would prefer to have one that would move it to its original directory.

Is this possible?

I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.4 and Terminal

Answer (score 3):

You will have to store where the original file is coming from then. Maybe in a seperate file, a database, or in the files attributes (meta-data).

Create a logfile with 2 columns:

1. The complete filename in the dustbin
2. The complete original path and filename

You will need this logfile anyway - what will you do when a user deleted 2 files in different directories, but with the same name? `/home/user/.wgetrc` and `/home/user/old/.wgetrc` ?

What will you do when a user deletes a file, makes a new one with the same name, and then deletes that too? You'll need versions or timestamps or something.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the original location somewhere, either in a database or in an extended attribute of the file.  A database is definitely the easiest way to do it, though an extended attribute would be more robust.  Looking in ~/.Trash/ I see some, but not all files have extended attributes, so I'm not sure how Apple does it.

Comment: I really like the extended attributes idea :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to somehow encode the source directory in the file. I think the easiest would be to change the filename in the dustbin directory. So that **/home/user/music/song.mp3** becomes **~/dustbin/song.mp3|home_user_music**

And when you copy it back your script needs to process the file name and construct the path beginning at |.

Comment: I think creating a database like others proposed is way to much for bash. If are going to do that then switch the language.

Comment: The problem here is that your filenames might have `|` in them already.  You could solve that by replacing `|` in the original filename with `||` (and reversing that when you restore it), since you can't have an empty directory name in a path.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to let the filesystem be your database.

A file moved from `/some/directory/somewhere/filename` would be moved to `~/dustbin/some/directory/somewhere/filename` and you'd do `find ~/dustbin -name "$file"` to find it based on its basename (from user input). Then you'd just trim "~/bustbin" from the output of `find` and you'd have the destination ready to use. If more than one file is returned by `find`, you can list the proposed files for user selection. You could use `~/dustbin/$deletiondate` if you wanted to make it possible to roll back to earlier versions.

You could do a `cron` job that would periodically remove old files and the directories (if empty).